# Intersection on two lines from 4 unknown points

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

Im just learning about intersection of lines and stuff. The problem i am currently into is to find the intersection point of two lines when four unknown points are given.

Through point slope form I can get the equation:

$y-y_1=(y_2-y_2)(x-x_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ for the first line and
$y-y_3=(y_4-y_3)(x-x_3)/(x_4-x_3)$ for the second line.

Through general equation formula I tried $ax+by+c=0$ where I replaced the value of a, b and c for both lines as:

$a=(y_1-y_2),b=(x_2-x_1),c=x_1*y_2 - x_2*y_1 $ for the first line and

$a=(y_3-y_4),b=(x_4-x_3),c=x_3*y_4 - x_4*y_3 $ for the second line.

I need to find the shortest equation for finding the value of $x$ and $y$ from both equations. I tried merging them into one formula but however I try, some results in long equation, some leads to confusing ones and the one I need is the easiest and shortest to calculate. If there is any formula I am missing, please help by suggesting them. I don't seem to find the problem on other similar questions, not even from google. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $y-y_1 = (y_2-y_2)(x-x_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ makes it $0$

Comment: I am supposed to find the value of x and y from those equations. they might result in other values as well other than 0

Comment: @Algebrology are there any other formulas to find the intersection of those lines defined by four unknown points?? If there are, please mention.